# What faster alternatives do I have to websockets for a real-time web application?

Tags: javascript, browser, websocket, network-programming

I'm planning to write a real time co-op multiplayer game. Currently I'm in the research phase. I've already written a turn-based game which used websockets and it was working fine.

I haven't tried writing a real time game using this technology however. My questions is about websockets. Is there an alternative way to handle communications between (browser) clients? My idea is to have the game state in each client and only send the deltas to the clients using the server as a mediator/synchronization tool.

My main concern is network speed. I want clients to be able to receive each other's actions as fast as possible so my game can stay real time. I have about 20-30 frames per second with less than a KByte of data per frame (which means a maximum of 20-30 KBytes of data per second per client).

I know that things like "network speed" depend on the connection but I'm interested in the "if all else equals" case.

Comment: how could something be faster than websockets, which lets you ship raw binary with just a few bytes overhead? 30kb/s is also too much for the general public, if it's tied to frames at all.

Comment: I don't know that's why I asked.

Comment: fair enough, my point is that with websockets you can ship data as fast as the network goes and with about as minimal latency and overhead as it gets. 30FPS should be no problem, socket trips are usually under 10ms (not counting TTFB), unless your server is far away, in which case it can take up to 15ms to go mostly around the world. 15ms*2=30ms round trip, 1000ms/30ms=33.3FPS. shipping pure deltas likely means shipping a key:value pair, but an ordered array of values-only would probably be "cheaper", even with the extra commas creating a sparse array whilst omitting redundant elements.

Comment: Sounds good. You may want to put that as an answer so I can upvote it.

Comment: @dandavis, latency times are much greater than you think.
transatlantic (eg: NY-London) is typically > 100ms.
if you are unlucky enough (from a network engineering perspective) to live in New Zealand you can expect at least 150ms to /any/ inexpensive datacentre based hosting.
many of the big telcos publish historical round trip times. eg:
http://www.verizonenterprise.com/about/network/latency/

Comment: @mrdunk: i wasn't talking about trip times, i was talking about how long it takes from when the server closes the connection to when the client parses the response, which takes nowhere near as long as half a round-trip... ex: CHI-SF takes about 70ms to ping, but the response usually arrives within 10-20ms after it's shipped once the connection is up and running... it's a question of how stale the server data is when it hits the client, and the answer is "not very" (relative to ping times)

Comment: @dandavis: fair point that time of flight will be better that half the RTT.
i was mostly disagreeing with your "it can take up to 15ms to go mostly around the world" comment.
as you say yourself, CHI-SF will take that long. if you are planning for a /global/ service you need to factor in longer times.

Comment: this prompted me to look up the /theoretical/ speed of transmission;
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optical_fiber states that the speed of light through fiber is ~200,000,000ms.

so CHI-SF would take 2,981,000meters / 200,000,000ms = 0.014905 seconds = ~15ms.

i'd regard "half way round the world" as something like New York to Sydney:
15,979,000meters / 200,000,000ms = 0.079895seconds = ~80ms.

these are the best /theoretical/ cases. the real world involves in-direct fiber paths, overloaded routers and gremlins.

Comment: the comment could have been better, no doubt... your math is good, but that server should ideally be halfway between sydney and ny in that case and also keep in mind packets can travel both ways at once, so with all that, i think 20FPS is doable. if OP only has one server for the world and users from everywhere, it's going to be tough w/o estimation/buffering/editing the past...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

From a standard browser, a webSocket is going to be your best bet.  The only two alternatives are webSocket and Ajax.  Both are TCP under the covers so once the connection is established they pretty much offer the same transport.  But, a webSocket is a persistent connection so you save connection overhead everytime you want to send something.  Plus the persistent connection of the webSocket allows you to send directly from server to client which you will want.

In a typical gaming design, the underlying gaming engine needs to adapt to the speed of the transport between the server and any given client.  If the client has a slower connection, then you have to drop the number of packets you send to something that can keep up (perhaps fewer frame updates in your case).  The connection speed is what it is so you have to make your app deliver the best experience you can at the speed that there is.

Some other things you can do to optimize the use of the transport:

1. Collect all data you need to send at one time and send it in one larger send operation rather than lots of small sends.  In a webSocket, don't send three separate messages each with their own data.  Instead, create one message that contains the info from all three messages.
2. Whenever possible, don't rely on the latency of the connection by sending, waiting for a response, sending again, waiting for response, etc...  Instead, try to parallelize operations so you send, send, send and then process responses as they come in.
3. Tweak settings for outgoing packets from your server so their is no Nagle delay waiting to see if there is other data to go in the same packet.  See [Nagle's Algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nagle%27s_algorithm).  I don't think you have the ability in a browser to tweak this from the client.
4. Make sure your data is encoded as efficiently as possible for smallest packet size.

Comment: you always have more (than two) alternatives :) You can use flash and create plain tcp/udp transport.

Comment: @PavelBucek - My answer says "from a standard browser".  Flash is not part of a standard browser and doesn't work at all from many browsers (like any mobile browser).  I can't imagine investing in designing anything these days that requires Flash.  If you want to that far, you can talk about Java plug-ins too.

Comment: true enough. My thinking was more about the OP scope - a browser game. Then you use flash more often. Or something like unity, which also provides networking support.

Comment: @adamarold - Did this answer your question well enough?  Or are there other issues you still want explanation for?